# What is passed as Sender on IBAction?

Tags: objective-c

When I use the code `-(IBAction) onClick1: (id) sender;`, what will be passed as `sender`? I tried to use the sender as the object id and fails (I mean I used the code `sender.tag` and it didn't return).

I am sure that when I am using `- (void)buttonTouched1:(UIButton *)sender;` here the sender should act as an object id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sender` variable is normally the object that sent the action message (this isn't exactly *guaranteed* — for example, you can send an action message yourself and pass anything you want — but that's how it's supposed to work).

You can't just write `sender.tag` in those methods because dot notation requires the object to have a static type so the compiler knows what message the property corresponds to. If you write `[sender tag]` instead, it will work.

Answer (score 6):

The sender is usually the object that will invoke the onClick1 message. For example if you have a button and you associate your -(IBAction)onClick1:(id)sender message with the "touch up inside" event of the button, then when you tap on the button, the object representing the button will be passed to onClick1:

```
-(IBAction)onClick1:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
   NSLog(@"%@", button);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to give the sender a static type if you're just logging it, and you wouldn't need to explicitly cast it anyway. And if you're going to treat the sender as a UIButton, you may as well just type the argument as a UIButton rather than creating a superfluous extra variable.

Comment: @Chuck Yes, if the only purpose is to log, then there's no need to cast. I only showed how to get the underlying object of the sender. While it's not necessary to cast the sender to UIButton in this case, casting will lead to cleaner and more readable code.